# paper only available in Russian (Kozachenko Leonenko entropy estimator)

Tags: it.information-theory, translation

this paper is only available in Russian: http://www.mathnet.ru/links/9f144b1d16e600dac49acbfe5acf938f/ppi797.pdf According to MathSciNet, there is no link to the English article or journal publication yet :(. I saw [this entry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245163/need-help-with-paper-written-in-russian-yorgovs-paper-on-self-dual-codes-wit) and tried Google translate - doesn't work.
But as I want to cite it, it would be cool to have read it.

Comment: the [English translation](https://link.springer.com/journal/11122/volumes-and-issues) of this journal only exists since 2001

Comment: And even it did not exist, there is the book "Russian for the mathematician"!

Comment: The link that you gave actually contains a reference to the English translation: Problems of Information Transmission, 1987, 23:2, 95–101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This journal is translated into English cover-to-cover
as *Problems of Information Transmission*.

Here is a PDF version of the indicated article for your convenience:

https://dmitripavlov.org/scans/kozachenko-leonenko.pdf